django-tables2 change headers for export
I'm trying to create different column header text when exporting a table.  The problem (I created) is when I render the table as a page, I wanted to append an icon to the column text to indicate it's sortable and the current direction of the sort.  My solution was to create an AbstractTable as follows:
class AbstractTable(Table):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for i in range(len(self.columns)):
        if is_blank(self.columns[i].column.verbose_name):
            my_label = self.columns[i].name.replace("_", " ").strip()
        else:
            my_label = self.columns[i].column.verbose_name.strip()

        arrow = '&#x21f5;' if self.columns[i].orderable else ""

        self.columns[i].column.verbose_name = mark_safe(f'{my_label} {arrow}')
    
def before_render(self, request):
    pprint(vars(request))
    if "sort" in request.GET:
        which_column = request.GET["sort"]
        reverse_sort = True if which_column[0] == "-" else False
        if reverse_sort:
            which_column = which_column[1:]
            arrow = '<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down-z-a"></i>'
        else:
            arrow = '<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down-a-z"></i>'
        i = [j for j in self.columns if j.name == which_column]

        new_name = i[0].verbose_name.replace(' &#x21f5;', '')

        i[0].column.verbose_name = mark_safe(f'{new_name} {arrow}')

then I do:
class StudentTable(AbstractTable)

and voila, it all works nicely - although I'm sure it can be improved.
Now the problem, when I export the table, my column headers in the csv or xls have the html code attached.  For example, if name is sortable, the export will have name &#x21f5; in the first row instead of just name.
What I can't figure out is how to tell if the request includes an export  (or not)  so I could modify the name appropriately.

The answer lays in how the table gets created.  Not thinking ahead when I appended the sorting symbol to the column header, I added it to the table's init().  I think the best answer would be to add a switch to the table init that, if the context is render/sort, add the symbol, but if the context is export, skip it.  But I can't figure out how to get this information (yet :-).
So I extended the ExportMixin to use an extension to ExportTable.  The extension is to table_to_dataset().  The code is included below:
class MyTableExport(TableExport):
    def table_to_dataset(self, table, exclude_columns, dataset_kwargs=None):
        """Transform a table to a tablib dataset."""

        print('in my table_to_dataset method')

        def default_dataset_title():
            try:
                return table.Meta.model._meta.verbose_name_plural.title()
            except AttributeError:
                return "Export Data"

        kwargs = {"title": default_dataset_title()}
        kwargs.update(dataset_kwargs or {})
        dataset = Dataset(**kwargs)
        for i, row in enumerate(table.as_values(exclude_columns=exclude_columns)):
            if i == 0:
                dataset.headers = row
                print('dataset.headers = ', dataset.headers)
            else:
                dataset.append(row)
        for i in range(len(dataset.headers)):
            print(f'counter = {i} and value is {dataset.headers[i]}')
            # remove any html special characters matching &#x21f5;
            dataset.headers[i] = dataset.headers[i].replace(UP_DOWN_ARROW, '').strip()
            print(f'\tafter and value is {dataset.headers[i]}')
        return dataset

